# MySQL reminder notification one month before expiration date (6 months)

Tags: php, mysql

I have found similar answers but I didn't find exact one, so I am starting a new question.

I have a little app for a mechanic shop, where the user can input information about the car, such as registration number, a name of the owner, date when the car was on service ( an auto added/updated field in MySQL).

My question is since all cars must do a service inspection again in 6 months, how can I after 5 months print out information that in next 30 days XY cars needs to make a new inspection?

**EDIT:**

***SELECT * FROM vozila where DATE_ADD(DATE(datum), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) = CURDATE()***

In case above, it is displaying only 5-month-old serviced cars from current date, but I need to set it to display notification 5 months after, and that that results stay on page for next 30 days (untill month 6th).

Let's say that some XY car was on the mechanic service at 1.1.2017... At 1.6.2017 on notification.php page there would be "Cars with expiration date in next 1 month:" table and on it would be all cars that are 1 month left up to 6th when then need to do it again.

Comment: Please be more specific. MySQL can't magically activate a printer. Are you looking for a specific query, or is this a question about cron jobs, ...?

Comment: _"but I didn't find exact one"_ - then take one of those answers and modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Your question is too broad and should be closed. In case you want to an answer, please edit and include your code that you have tried and doesn't work. Since your question is too broad, therefore the answer I can think of is broad as well. You will have to run Cron Jobs.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM vozila where datum < date_sub(now(), interval 5 months)" -> this command is displaying cars that are 5 months after service, but... "expiration date" needs to be 6 months after input date( "datum"), so I need information when they are one month neer expiration date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SELECT * FROM vozila where datum < date_sub(now(), interval 11 month)"